# When I change a document so that it no longer matches a query, why does the Firestore listener still fetch the original document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore listener with a query that looks like this:

```
firestore
  .collection(`users/${uid}/${collection}`)
  .where('isArchived', '==', false)
  .onSnapshot(
    { includeMetadataChanges },
    snapshot => {
      console.log('snapshot.metadata', snapshot.metadata);
      console.log('docChanges:')
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(
        ({ doc }) => console.log(doc.id, doc.data())
      );
      console.log('docs:')
      snapshot.forEach(
        (doc) => console.log(doc.id, doc.data())
      );

      dispatch(fetchItemsFulfilled({ collection, snapshot}));
    },
     error => dispatch(fetchItemsRejected(error.toString())),
  );
```

Basically, I am filtering out archived documents from the query.

The problem I have is that when I set a document field `isArchived` from `false` to `true`, the listener snapshot receives the unchanged document where `isArchived` is still `false`.

Is this the expected behavior? I would have expected that the listener should receive no changes since the modified document no longer matches the query.

console logs before:

```
snapshot.metadata {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
docChanges:
2k0dl69Q8Zm5CjSCZtvy {isArchived: false, ...}
9MnJOEAOuJKbmTbkw5X8 {isArchived: false, ...}
MJEHXtvbSPkRC0V8l8RW {isArchived: false, ...}
docData:
2k0dl69Q8Zm5CjSCZtvy {isArchived: false, ...}
9MnJOEAOuJKbmTbkw5X8 {isArchived: false, ...}
MJEHXtvbSPkRC0V8l8RW {isArchived: false, ...}
```

after setting document MJEHXtvbSPkRC0V8l8RW isArchived to `true`:

```
snapshot.metadata {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
docChanges:
MJEHXtvbSPkRC0V8l8RW {isArchived: false, ...}
docData:
2k0dl69Q8Zm5CjSCZtvy {isArchived: false, ...}
9MnJOEAOuJKbmTbkw5X8 {isArchived: false, ...}
```

As you can see, docChanges for MJEHXtvbSPkRC0V8l8RW has isArchived ===  false even though it was just set to true.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the behavior you're seeing. Can you log the document ID, the `isArchived` value, and the [`fromCache` metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#fromcache) in the listener, and then show the updated code and what output you get?

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the reply. So I just looked a bit deeper into my code and realized that I'm using snapshot.docChanges() – the reason is because my app has a lot of documents and I only want to fetch and update changes rather than the entire query.

So if I modify a document on doc id `PL0aCbQgpLltAW4BHp5X` to change the field `isArchived` from `false` to `true`, then the following happens:
1. snapshot returns the expected documents excluding the doc id `PL0aCbQgpLltAW4BHp5X`
2. snapshot.docChanges returns just the one document `PL0aCbQgpLltAW4BHp5X` BEFORE the document was modified

Comment: That's what was confusing me ... I was expecting to see the document `PL0aCbQgpLltAW4BHp5X` AFTER the document was modified (i.e `isArchived` set to true). I guess I'm going to have to figure out some other way to update my app's state for archived items. I really wanted to use snapshot.docChanges rather than snapshot because if my query returns 2000 item but I only modify one document, I don't want to have to receive and process 2000 items.

Comment: Hey @stevenkim. It is hard to digest what you're saying in comments. Can you edit your question to include the updated code, and its output?

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your patience. Just updated the code per your request. I think this is just the way Firestore works, and I need to find a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for that update @stevenkin. I must admit I don't regularly listen for `includeMetadataChanges`. My guess it that the `onSnapshot` listener immediately fires for the local change, which would mean that the `DocumentSnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites` would be `true` at that point. But this is pretty much just an educated guess.